# How to fix parameters in parameterized test?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, parameterized-tests

I am using gtest for my tests and i am discovering value-parameterized tests.
I understand the google example with

```
int tab[] = {1, 2, 3};    
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(MyTestName, MyTest, ::testingCombine(Bool(), ::testing::ValuesIn(tab)));
```

It is testing all combinations of 'true' with {1, 2, 3} and 'false' with {1,2,3}.

1. If i want to fix the Boolean to 'false', how do i do ?
2. And i want to test several combinations like (true, ::testing::ValuesIn(tab)), (true, ::testing::ValuesIn(tab2)) , (false, ::testing::ValuesIn(tab3)) ?

Well, i am lost.

Comment: I find a way but i wish it still could exist a more elegant way with a "::testingValueIn".
I use an array of std::tuple<bool, int>: 
`std::tuple<bool, int> tab[] =
{
    std::make_tuple(true, 1),
    std::make_tuple(true, 12)
};`

Comment: Another possibility for fixing a parameter is to use a one element array.  `bool tabBool[] = {true};
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(MyTestName, MyTest, ::testingCombine(::testing::ValuesIn(tabBool), ::testing::ValuesIn(tab)));`